# Script scraper for outputting variables and functions to a text file

Tags: python, optimization, python-2.x

I've been programming with Python 2.7 for about six months now and if possible, I'd like some critique to see what I might have done better or what I might be doing wrong.

My objective was to make a script scraper that finds variables and functions, outputting them to a text file along with their line number. It also organizes the output based on type and string length for readability. It works as intended, but I'd like to know if/how I could have wrote it better, cleaner.

```
import re



def change_line():
        parse_next['line_count'] += 1

def make_readable(list):
        fix_order = {}
        for item in list:
                fix_order[len(item)] = item
        return sort_this(fix_order)


def sort_this(dict):
        fixed = dict.keys()
        fixed.sort()
        newly_ordered = []
        for number in fixed:
                newly_ordered.append(dict[number])
        return newly_ordered   


def parse_match(match):
        if '\n' in match:
                parse_next[match]()
        elif 'def' in match:
                parse_next[match] = parse_next['line_count']
                funcs.append(match)
        elif match:
                parse_next[match] = parse_next['line_count']
                varis.append(match)
        else:
                print 'error'



funcs = []
varis = []             
txt_file = open('c:\\code\\test.txt', 'r')
output = open('c:\\code\\output.txt', 'w+')
found = re.findall(r'\n|def\s.+|.+ = .+', txt_file.read())


parse_next = {
        '\n': change_line,
        'line_count': 1,
}

for match in found:
        parse_match(match)


funcs = make_readable(funcs)
varis = make_readable(varis)   
output.write('\t:Functions:\n\n')

for item in funcs:
        s_fix = item.replace('def ', '',)
        to_write = [s_fix, ' Line:', str(parse_next.get(item)), '\n']
        output.writelines(to_write)

output.write('\n'*2)
output.write('\t:Variables:\n\n')

for item in varis:
        to_write = [item.strip(),' Line:', str(parse_next.get(item)), '\n']
        output.writelines(to_write)


output.close()
txt_file.close()
```

To run it, you'll need to edit this filepath:

```
txt_file = open('c:\code\test.txt', 'r')
```

with code from a script of your choice.

Be harsh if necessary, I'd really like to get better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

---

`make_readable` has a very serious problem - what if two inputs have the same length? A dictionary can only have one value per key; I suggest making it a dictionary of lists of items (or a `collections.defaultdict(list)`) instead. Also, don't call the argument `list` - that's a built-in.

---

`sort_this` could be shortened (and the argument shouldn't be called `dict`):

```
def sort_this(d):
    return [d[key] for key in sorted(d)]
```

Iterating over a dictionary (e.g. in `sorted`) automatically iterates over the keys. Also, this will work without modification in Python 3.x (where `fixed.sort()` will fail).

---

The `global` variables (e.g. `funcs`) should either be *explicitly global* (i.e. put `global funcs` at the start of functions that use them) or, much better, passed as arguments to the functions:

```
def parse_match(match, funcs, varis, parse_next):
```

---

One bug you may want to look into - if a variable is defined over multiple lines:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3,
           4, 5, 6]
```

Your code only gets the start of the definition.

---

Finally, it would be neat to not have to change the hard-coded strings to change the files to analyse and output to! Look into taking command line arguments (`sys.argv`) or using e.g. `tkinter` to put a GUI in. At the very least, have a higher-level function `analyse(input_file, output_file)` then call it at the end of your script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    analyse("C:\\code\\test.txt", "C:\\code\\output.txt")
```

It is not best practice to put the variables you have to change somewhere in the middle of the file - top or bottom is easier to find!

Comment: Thanks man! I'll post an updated version of the script once i fix everything. Might be a day or so before i get back and post it though.

Comment: Posted an edited version, but I found a major bug. I'll reupdate when it's fixed.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think I'm going to be able to fix it this time. I fed it a few different inputs and it gave me a different error every time. It would be so much easier to just remake the whole thing with the bug in mind.